# Parallel processing of large collections

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

I have a large collection in a JSONL file, that does not fit in memory, I currently read it through pandas with the usage of chunks that are returned as DataFrames. For each df I process it and create a index file. So my question is how to create the index in parallel? As of right now my code stands as written below, there are other sections of processing for the chunk (that I omitted here), and for some reason the 'done' print never is executed.

What I actually need is to process a part of the collection, create an index file and move to another part, and do that in mutiple threads. Also important is to free memory after the process is concluded. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Restrictions: Only allowed to use native python and pandas

```
def chunk_handler(chunk):
    print('1')
    texts = chunk['text']
    print('2')
    for i in texts:
        pre_process(i)
    print('3')
    chunk.to_csv('tests/' + len(os.listdir()) + '.csv', index=False)
    print('done')

def load_data(path: str):

    with pd.read_json(path, lines=True, chunksize=10000) as reader:
    pool = mp.Pool(4)

    ll_ = []
    for chunk in reader:
        res = pool.apply_async(chunk_handler, (chunk,))
    
    ll_.append(res)
```

I played around with the .get(), .join() and other functions to see if anything changed, the ll_ list was added as a test but seems to make the function actually be executed. I don't care about the structure, I just need to read the file in chunks and index those chunks in a new file for each chunk